# call a procedure inside exception

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I need to call a anonimous procedure inside an exception that was call inside other procedure. as exemplo below:

```
    procedure p1 is
    begin
      begin
        select 1 from dual;
      exception
        when no_data_found then
          p2;
      end;
    end;
    end p1;

    procedure p2 is
    [process..]
    end p2;
    begin
        p1;
    end;
    /
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

No problem in doing that; however, if you want to run an **anonymous** piece of code, then it is not a *stored procedure*, because they are *named* (i.e. not anonymous).

Here's an example:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p1 as
  2    l_dummy number(1);
  3  begin
  4    select 1 into l_dummy from dual where 1 = 2;
  5  exception
  6    when no_data_found then
  7      begin
  8        select 2 into l_dummy from dual;
  9        dbms_output.put_line('Exception, selected value = ' || l_dummy);
 10      end;
 11  end;
 12  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  2    p1;
  3  end;
  4  /
Exception, selected value = 2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

If you want to call a stored procedure, no problem either:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p2 as
  2    l_dummy number(1);
  3  begin
  4    select 3 into l_dummy from dual;
  5    dbms_output.put_line('P2: selected value = ' || l_dummy);
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL> create or replace procedure p1 as
  2    l_dummy number(1);
  3  begin
  4    select 1 into l_dummy from dual where 1 = 2;
  5  exception
  6    when no_data_found then
  7      p2;
  8  end;
  9  /

Procedure created.

SQL> begin
  2    p1;
  3  end;
  4  /
P2: selected value = 3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

As you can see, both options work.

Answer (score 0):

You could create "anonymous"(should say nested) procedure p2 inside p1:

```
create or replace procedure p1 
is
    c INT;

    procedure p2 is
    begin
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Procedure p2');
    end p2;
begin
    select 1 INTO c from dual where 1=0;
    exception
    when no_data_found then
      p2;
end p1;
//
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ac958a268994a043d6507c65aae32350)**

Answer (score 0):

You can declare procedures inside an anonymous PL/SQL block.  Any procedures you declare inside an anonymous PL/SQL block will exist only within that block and be visible only within that block.

For example, (shamelessly stealing code for `p1` and `p2` from LittleFoot):

```
DECLARE
   -- Forward declaration for p2, so p1 can see it.  
   -- Alternatively, you could just put the whole definition of p2 here instead.
   procedure p2;

   procedure p1 as
      l_dummy number(1);
    begin
      select 1 into l_dummy from dual where 1 = 2;
    exception
      when no_data_found then
        p2;
    end p1;

    procedure p2 as
      l_dummy number(1);
    begin
      select 3 into l_dummy from dual;
      dbms_output.put_line('P2: selected value = ' || l_dummy);
    end p2;


BEGIN
      p1;
END;
```